# How to simplify the following regex

Tags: c#, regex, simplify

I'm trying to match pattern that represent dimension like :

```
2,2x3
3*5
4  X 44,5
5x5x5
```

Numbers can be either double (using dot or comma) or int. Separator can either be xX*/\ (and can be mixed to, like:  5*3x9). There is a maximum of 3 numbers in the dimension and the 3rd one is not mandatory (i often match only 2 dimension). There can be any number of space between number and separator. Im using this regexp which is working quiet fine but i wondered if there would be any easier way of achieving it :

```
(\d+[.,]?\d*)\s*[xX*/\\]\s*(\d+[.,]?\d*)(\s*[xX*/\\]\s*(\d+[.,]?\d*))?
```

Comment: You may use the following [regex](http://regex101.com/r/wM6qV6).

Comment: Why does it have to be one regex? You can split it into 4 different ones, each much simpler than what you have.

Comment: Nice website but it is ironic though that the web used regex to search for regex pattern to describe regex syntaxes

Comment: @Oded I Dont get what you mean, i need to match this pattern in strings so i need a full regex to capture those specific groups

Comment: I would not go with a regex, to make the code more readable :

First do a pass with String.Split() to get the number.
Then do one (or two) pass with String.IndexOfAny() to get the separators.

Comment: @Fendy I dont follow you there ...

Comment: Your regex is OK. It's captures dimension to $1,$2,$3 (with $3 is optional), handles decimal values (.,) and allows many separators between numbers. If it works and hasn't performance problems - use it.. ;)

Comment: I mean, you can use 4, simple regular expressions instead of 1 really complex one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted a previous answer where I had misread part of your question.  So this is a re-do.

In all honesty, this is the best Regex Statement:

```
(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)\s*[xX*/\\]\s*(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)(?:\s*[xX*/\\]\s*(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?))?
```

Why?  Because with this statement, you have a Group 1, Group 2, and Group 3 from which you can pull your three values (The third may sometimes be blank, obviously).  If you use quantifiers to repeat a sub-expression, you would have to get into group collections and your code would get messy.

What's the difference between my long one, and your long one?  Well, the long one above has better handling for "decimals", whereas yours would allow improper numbers such as "382.".

But if shorter is the route you want to take, the Regex would be:

```
(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)(?:\s*[xX*/\\]\s*(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)){1,2}
```

In this case, your code could pull the first value from Group 1, but then would have to use a group collection to see if Group 2 has a stack or just a single value.  If it's a stack, get capture collection item 0 for value 2, then capture collection item 1 for value 3.

These regexes are very simlar to Stema's, except they organize capture groups.

The Breakdown:

```
(              //Capture Group 1 - Begin
  \d+          //Require Digits
  (?:          //Non Capture Sub Expression
    [.,]\d+    //Allow a "Decimal", but if it exists, Require Digits after it
  )?           //Optional Quantifier for the "decimal" sub-expression
)              //Capture Group 1 - End
(?:            //Non Capture Sub Expression
  \s*          //Optionally capture space(s)
  [xX*/\\]     //Require a Separator
  \s*          //Optional capture space(s)
  (            //Capture Group 2 - Begin
    \d+        //Require Digits
    (?:        //Non Capture Sub Expression
      [.,]\d+  //Allow a "Decimal", but if it exists, Require Digits after it
    )?         //Optional Quantifier for the "decimal" sub-expression
  )            //Capture Group 2 - End
){1,2}         //Require at least one Separator/Digit pattern, but allow two
```

Again, the difference between my "short" answer and Stema's, is just that mine handles "Decimals" more appropriately.  But you may not require that extra security, in which case stema's is fine.  Also, use non-capture expressions when you are just using a sub-expression for grouping or repetition, and don't want to capture it.  In the long run, adding values to those stacks does weigh a little on your processing speed.

So if you don't care about capture groups, processing perfection, or proper decimal handling... and all you want is the shortest possible regex, Stema hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the quantifier `{1,2}`, means match one or two times. The last optional group is the same than the past in the middle of your regex. so just remove the duplicated part and use that quantifier on the group.

```
(\d+[.,]?\d*)(\s*[xX*/\\]\s*(\d+[.,]?\d*)){1,2}
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?353t1). I added the anchors `^` and `$`, depends on the method you use in .net if you need them or not.

Comment: this would not do it, since matching two times this is not matching the same as matching the pattern with 3 number : this version does not allow 3*3*3.

Comment: @C4stor check the regexr link. Of course it is matching "3*3*3". I just removed the last optional part.

Comment: Well that's actually usefull, didnt think of quantifier, im testing this at the moment thanks